# How to copy cookies in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Is there any way I can copy/edit the cookies in Chrome Developer tools? Or do I need to install a custom add-on for this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think I have found something. I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and Drag & Drop the values in a TextBox and then copy it from there.

As pointed by @jmccure,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click and copy.

Update: [Chrome 58](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/devtools-release-notes) added a support to edit cookies

Comment: Thanks. Also, it's ridiculous that you have to do this at all. Come on Google.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for me (while CTRL + A and SHIFT works, you could change the answer I think..)

Comment: This solution works for GUI automation scripts. Great job

Answer (score 43):

Cross-browser Solution:

1. Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> or Right-click page and Inspect to open the Developer Tools
2. Click the Application Tab *(which used to be called Resources)*
3. Open Cookies on the left, select your site/domain
4. Double-click cookie column *Value*
5. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or Right-click and select Copy

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Chrome if the cookie has some "delimiter" characters, such as +, =, etc.

Comment: This only gives you the value. I'd still have to copy the Expire/HttpOnly/path/domain by hand wouldn't I?

Comment: There's no "Resources" tab in Developer Tools in Chrome. This answer is outdated. Using Chrome 56.

Comment: Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C (to copy all) got broken in more recent versions (as usual - new version, new mess-up :-) In 58 was still OK in 67 not. Root cause - new preview pane handling. Now Ctrl-A selects 3rd pane as well and then Ctrl-C fails and R-Click Copy is gone. Temp solution - have to drag to select everything in just 2 panes - then Ctrl-C works again. If you have "too many" cookies == they fill the whole pane then dragging has to start from top left corner. It Shift-Up/Down was working for line-by-line selection it would be easier.

Comment: Seems to still work for me. I just tested by double-clicking the value column on  some sites with very long cookies and was able to get the full value.

Answer (score 26):

If you have a lot of cookies and you don't want to install any plugin, I created a small script to avoid copying the cookies one by one.

It was tested only in Google Chrome.

```
// Open the console in the developer tools

// Tab where you are getting the cookies from
// This block can be just copy and paste

let cookies = document.cookie;
cookies = cookies.split(";");
cookies = cookies.map(cookie => cookie.replace(" ", ""));
copy(cookies);

// Tab where you want to have the cookies
// This block cannot be copy and paste since there is no function to paste

const newCookies = // paste your cookies array here
newCookies.map(newCookie => {
    document.cookie = newCookie;
})
```

Comment: I like this approach, but it doesn't get any cookies marked HTTPOnly. Depending on your needs, this may or may not matter.

Comment: @pkaeding It mattered to me.

Comment: Though it doesen't work with HTTPOnly cookies instantly there is a workaround. One can disable this flag first and then reeanable after the pasting step.

Comment: I like this solution as a stepping stone for my idea. Basically copy and paste cookie into email. Email cookie to yourself. Then in a different browser manufacturer, open email, copy to clipboard and then paste into new cookie. Have you made any enhancements to your copy process since this answer?

Comment: Here are my [future plans for revolutionizing cookies](https://pippim.github.io/mt.html#future-plans) I'd really like to know if you've done any work closely related. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

An alternative approach to copy a long cookie value:

1. Repeat the request with the **Network** tab open.
2. Right-click the relevant request (in the list on the left-hand side).
3. Choose **Copy as cURL**.
4. Extract the cookie from the generated `Cookie` header option.

For example: `curl 'http://...' -H 'Cookie: session=...' ...`

Comment: As of Oct 2016 - This works in Firefox, but no longer works in Chrome: it copies the cURL request but doesn't give you the cookies used

Comment: Aug 2018 - Works fine for me in Chrome, puts cookies in the request correctly.

Comment: It's 2022, and I found out it's significantly easier to go to the Network tab and copy the Cookie header than anything else on Chrome right now.

Answer (score 14):

This sounds strange, but if you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click, it seems to work *most* of the time.

Comment: For this to work you need to first left click at the beginning of the cookie value and right click with shift at the end or in the next line: so it is better to use ctrl-a as pointed by user user960567

Answer (score 8):

I use the [Edit this Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) extension for Google Chrome, which is very nice.

According to its documentation:

> EditThisCookie is a cookie manager. You can add, delete, edit, search,
>   protect and block cookies!

Comment: I could export cookies using this ext .. But, I could not get to import those.... So, I did added the cookies manually !  Then, it worked....

Answer (score 4):

You have to select the value and then you can copy it. Double click helps, but if there are some delimiter characters (e.g. ".", "-" etc.) then you have to triple click it (at least in Windows 10).

So basically:

1. select the value (double or triple click)
2. copy the selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or "Copy" from context menu)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any reliable way to do this from developer tools. Right clicking the value and choosing copy sometimes works, but not if there are delimeter characters.

One workaround is to go into the js console and print `document.cookie`. Unfortunately, that only works for non HTTP_Only cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Another combination that works: Click on cookie value.  **While holding the left mouse button**, click right button thrice. The Copy command will now appear in the shortcut menu.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to copy my Instagram session to another browser. So I went this way successfully.

### On the source browser

1. Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> / go to Dev Tools
2. Go to the network tab
3. Reload the page / hit <kbd>F5</kbd>
4. Scroll up to the very first entry (document http/200)
5. Click it and go to the headers tab
6. Find the cookie header and right click / copy value

### On the target browser

1. Go the other browser and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> / go to Dev Tools
2. Go to the console
3. Type `''.split(';').forEach(c => document.cookie=c);`
4. Paste your cookie value between the single(!) quotes and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
5. Reload the page / hit <kbd>F5</kbd>